# How can i pass file as parameter in post request (Web Activity) Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure, api, azure-data-factory

I need to send request to API over Azure Data Factory. But input parameter is file. How can i do this?

Comment: Hello Andrew Yanchak, If my answer is helpful for you, please mark it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Data Factory [Web Active](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-web-activity) can help you achieve that. It depends on where the file location is.

For example, if your parameter file is stored in Blob Storage.

We can set the `filename` as dataset parameter:
[image]

Then set pipeline parameter `filename`:
[image]

Web active settings:

Set dataset filename = `@pipeline().parameters.filename`
[image]

We can not pass a file as parameter directly, but we could parameter the filename to set the file in source dataset.

Hope this helps you.