# POST data to REST API using Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, api, azure-data-factory

I am trying to setup Web activity to POST data from Azure Data Lake Gen 1 to REST API service, followed similar setup performed in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62322109/how-can-i-pass-file-as-parameter-in-post-request-web-activity-azure-data-facto/62336108#62336108) but couldn't succeed due to error 'Missing file'.

Sample CURL request - Successful when attempted with POSTMAN

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://xxxx/files' \
--header 'X-API-TOKEN: xxxx' \
--form 'file=xxxxx'
```

Dataset settings:
[image]

Web activity settings:

[image]

Run Error:
[image]

Comment: what the whole error message? can you us some screenshots?

Comment: @LeonYue updated question with detail screenshot. please refer

Answer (score 2):

Raised ticket on this to Microsoft and they stated this feature is yet to be implemented for Data Factory.

But for now I have achieved this through Logic Apps.

Logic Apps supports multiform data, where the data is read from Data lake and named as a file before sending it as attachment to target server.

[image]

```
{
  "$content-type": "multipart/form-data",
  "$multipart": [
    {
      "body": "@{body('Read_File_from_Data_Lake')}",
      "headers": {
        "Content-Disposition": "form-data; name=file; filename=Sample.csv"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is now supported I have done this today, you need to select POST on the REST activity

[image: POST Example in Data Flow]

and the body is created from the mapping fields. Each mapped field represents a JSON element in the body object.

[image]

This will result in the body of the request being:

```
{
    "jsonElement1" : "<my_row_status_value>",
    "jsonElement2" : "<my_row_ProductType_value>"
}
```