# Use a JSON body query on a REST Web service in Azure Data Factory v2

Tags: json, azure, azure-data-factory

My goal is to authenticate on a JSON web service :

```
POST /api/authenticate/basic HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 123
Host: test.biz

{
  "login" : "user",
  "password" : "pass",
  "site" : "foo-site"
}
```

I need to use a JSON array in the request body. Sadly on Microsoft documentation they say that they don't support JSON request.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-rest?tabs=synapse-analytics

> REST connector ignores any "Accept" header specified in
> additionalHeaders. As REST connector only support response in JSON, it
> will auto generate a header of Accept: application/json.

It seems that we can send a file in the body, but it is a bit unclear for me.

[POST data to REST API using Azure Data Factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62940780/post-data-to-rest-api-using-azure-data-factory)

Is it possible to implement that JSON query into a data flow ? and just get the token

And in a second goal, for security reason, I prefer to generate it with the password of the vault. is it possible to create dynamically generate the JSON array?

Comment: Have you tried sending a JSON body in your post request? What is the error you are receiving? The documentation just states that for the Rest connector, the response has to be in JSON. You cannot use the connector for a xml response(for example). Yes, you can extract the token out of the JSON response. With ADF, you cannot use the keyvault for anything in the JSON body. ADF can use the vault if the credentials were on the header.

Comment: I managed to it with a web request object.  I think we can't set POST request on others objects. Can you check if I'm wrong ?  Btw I'll post my solution. Do you know if I can process a json response issue from a web request object ? Regards

Comment: Yes, you can use a JSON body with a POST with a rest connector and yes you can extract a certain field from your response. Have a look at my answer for all the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you are allowed to put a JSON body in a Rest API POST but you can't set this in the Linked service or dataset, you need to set it in the Copy activity itself See the below pic and ADF code.
[image]

```
{
    "name": "Copy data1",
    "type": "Copy",
    "dependsOn": [],
    "policy": {
        "timeout": "7.00:00:00",
        "retry": 0,
        "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
        "secureOutput": false,
        "secureInput": false
    },
    "userProperties": [],
    "typeProperties": {
        "source": {
            "type": "RestSource",
            "httpRequestTimeout": "00:01:40",
            "requestInterval": "00.00:00:00.010",
            "requestMethod": "POST",
            "requestBody": "{\n    \"method\": \"GetFeed\",\n    \"params\": {\n        \"credentials\": {\n            \"database\": \"aci_logistics\",\n            \"sessionId\": \"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\",\n            \"userName\": \"xxxxxxxxxxx@x.com\"\n        },\n        \"typeName\": \"LogRecord\",\n        \"search\": {\n            \"fromDate\": \"2021-09-28T00:00:00.000Z\",\n            \"toDate\": \"2021-08-01T01:00:00.000Z\"\n        }\n    }\n}"
        },
        "sink": {
            "type": "JsonSink",
            "storeSettings": {
                "type": "AzureDataLakeStoreWriteSettings"
            },
            "formatSettings": {
                "type": "JsonWriteSettings"
            }
        },
        "enableStaging": false
    },
    "inputs": [
        {
            "referenceName": "RestResource4",
            "type": "DatasetReference"
        }
    ],
    "outputs": [
        {
            "referenceName": "Json3",
            "type": "DatasetReference"
        }
    ]
}
```

Secondly, yes, you can extract a certain field from the result of your POST. Assuming you have already created a variable. You will need a set variable activity (like you already have). The value would be the output of your web activity but depends on which field you need and the structure/format of the result of your POST. In my example, I got a JSON result as below.

```
{
    "result": {
        "credentials": {
            "database": "xxxxx",
            "sessionId": "xxxxxxx",
            "userName": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        }
    }
}
```

Let's say I wanted to extract the sessionId, the value in my Set variable activity would look something like

```
@activity('Web1').output.result.credentials.sessionId
```

Comment: That sounds great, I'll try it. Do you know how if I can generate the JSON request dynamically or put the the vault ?

Comment: There is no out of the box way to store JSON body fields into the AKV like we have for other connectors/linked services. You will need an additional step to retrieve the secret from the key vault using a rest or http connector. Then use dynamic content to concatenate the different fields you need in your JSON body. If you switch on the "Secure input and outputs" in the General tab of the activity, the secrets will be hidden from history so no one can see them. The Getsecret API is detailed in this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/get-secret

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that we can't set the POST request in a REST linked service or a dataset.

We can resolve the issue wit a "Web request" component inside a pipeline.

[image: working example on adf]

```
{
    "name": "pipeline1",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "Web1",
                "type": "WebActivity",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "7.00:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "url": "https://d1.a.biz/api",
                    "method": "POST",
                    "body": {
                        "login": "",
                        "password": "",
                        "site": ""
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Set variable1",
                "type": "SetVariable",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "Web1",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "variableName": "token",
                    "value": {
                        "value": "@activity('Web1').output.Response",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        "variables": {
            "token": {
                "type": "String"
            }
        },
        "annotations": []
    } }
```