# Pass data from CSV file to Salesforce using Salesforce Bulk API via Azure Data Factory

Tags: api, salesforce, azure-data-factory

I am trying to bulk upload data to Salesforce using Salesforce Bulk API in Azure Data Factory but getting the following error when I pass the csv file as a parameter as per this link [How can i pass file as parameter in post request (Web Activity) Azure Data Factory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62322109/how-can-i-pass-file-as-parameter-in-post-request-web-activity-azure-data-facto/62336108#62336108)

[image]

Below is my pipeline:

I am getting access token from Salesforce which I pass on to the next Web Activity which creates the job and then the 3rd web activity uploads the data to Salesforce, that's when I get the error

Create Bulk Job details:
[image]

Upload Bulk Job Details:
[image]

Parameter at pipeline level:
[image]

Parameter at Dataset:
[image]

Is it even possible to pass data from csv file in Azure Data Factory's Web Activity?

Comment: Can you try a specific file name as a test?

Comment: @LeonYue it doesn't work even if I give a specific filename. Do I have to use ingest/batches in URL and PUT in method in the Upload Job activity, because if I remove the batches from the URL and use POST instead of PUT I get error
[{"errorCode":"API_ERROR","message":"MediaType of 'text/csv' is not supported by this resource"}]. I guess it doesn't like the content-type in the header for the Upload Job Activity

Comment: Hi @Mariya, That may be a good idea, please try it and waiting for the update.

Comment: Hello @Mariya, hope you're doing well, do you get any progresses?

Comment: Hi Lean, I was not able to achieve what I was trying to with this approach, but I used web activity with GET method to read the CSF file and then merge the create job with the web activity to insert the data in SF. Thanks for your input. It was good to try it out but in our case it didn't work

Comment: thank  for sharing!  Is that workaround "use web activity with GET method to read the CSF file and then merge the create job with the web activity to insert the data in SF" could solve your problem? May I post this as the answer?